# How to hide empty adsense box

Tags: jquery, iframe, html, adsense

How to hide adsense iframe/div when no ads for this box are available?

Comment: don't do this. It's against the TOS. Google will ban you. And they will ban you for good.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

much better idea:
http://www.google.com/support/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=21590&rd=1

Comment: I don't see any answer to your question in the link that you added

Comment: It is recommended to not use links as answers as they don't age well. For example this link no longer has any relevancy to the question.

Please see my answer below, Google recommends using CSS to hide empty and unfilled ads.

Answer (score 3):

The official recommendation from Google is to use CSS.

Google uses data-ad-status to indicate if an ad placement was filled or not, which can be targeted to apply CSS to hide the element.

```
ins.adsbygoogle[data-ad-status="unfilled"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

From Google's support article: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10762946?hl=en

Comment: In some occasions i have observed filled ad units are added data-ad-status="unfilled" status, it might hide them as well, may be it was a bug, but better to observe a few times and implements this solution.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid violating AdSense's terms of service, I'd recommend setting up Google's DFP SB - it's a free adserver and really easy to link your adsense account. Then create a house ad (any ad that advertises a paid version of your site or your twitter account, etc) you can then set-up DFP to serve your house ad anytime Adsense can't fill.

Answer (score -2):

Get the name/ID of the iframe and just use [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

If you can't find a suitable selector, wrap the ad in a div with an id e.g.

```
<div id='some_google_ad'>
 // Google add code goes in here
</div>
```

and in your javacsript

```
$("#some_google_ad").hide();
```

Note there is no way of telling if your ad or ads are showing a community service announcement or a paid advertisement.

And I would suspect that having an adsense ad container on a page and having it hidden would be against the adsense TOS.